# maven2: excluding directory from WAR

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-war-plugin

I tried [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) to exclude whole directory (${basedir}/src/main/webapp/webscripts) from my WAR file but it failed. What is wrong?

this doesn't work:

```
<configuration>
   <webResources>
      <resource>
       <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/webscripts</directory>
       <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
       </excludes>
      </resource>
   </webResources>
</configuration>
```

this too:

```
<configuration>
   <webResources>
      <resource>
       <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
       <excludes>
        <exclude>**/webscripts</exclude>
       </excludes>
      </resource>
   </webResources>
</configuration>
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Just move it to a different location. Why is webscripts under webapp ?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Both of your solutions wouldn't help, as they would add an additional resource that is then deactivated. The webapp source folder is copied by default, without the resource mechanism.

The mechanism to deactivate a part of that is through the [`<warSourceExcludes>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceExcludes) parameter, like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceExcludes>webscripts/**</warSourceExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Just an addition, if you wanted to exclude several folders add them after a comma, dont use several warSourceExcludes, it wouldn't work

Comment: how to exclude multiple directories.

Comment: Just use list of values separated by comma inside warSourceExcludes tag.

Answer (score 33):

**warSourceExcludes** seems not to have been just renamed **packagingExcludes**.

> **warSourceExcludes**: The comma separated list of tokens to exclude when copying the content of the warSourceDirectory.
>
> **packagingExcludes**: The comma separated list of tokens to exclude from the WAR before packaging. This option may be used to implement
>   the skinny WAR use case.

There is a big difference: With **packagingExcludes**, the tokens are completely excluded from the final war file. With **warSourceExcludes**, the tokens are just ignored when copying the war directory into the war file.
As a result, if the tokens are present in the **webappDirectory** for example, they will not be ignored when using **warSourceExcludes** but will be when using **packagingExcludes**.

And a working syntax example:

```
<warSourceExcludes>**/${project.artifactId}/**</warSourceExcludes>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ignored when copying"??? If they are not copied to the war file - they are not packaged in the war file, and it's the same as packagingExcludes. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: packagingExcludes doesn't copy to final war while warSourceExcludes doesn't copy to warDirectory that will be compressed to a war.

Answer (score 6):

In version 2.1-alpha-1, this was incorrectly named warSourceExcludes. The right parameter is [packagingExcludes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#packagingExcludes)

Example of usage (excludes WEB-INF/statics/ folder from WAR):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>searchservice-web</warName>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/statics/</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This is incorrect and misled me for a while. I am using version 2.1.1, but packagingExcludes does not work, while warSourceExcludes does. It looks like in newer versions the packagingExcludes is the correct tag to use.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Project Structure]

Inorder to remove the source files i have used the below configuration in maven

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <packagingExcludes>
        eb-app/app/**,eb-app/node_modules/**,eb-app/public/**,eb-app/server/**,eb-app/tests/**,eb-app/tmp/**,eb-app/vendor/**,eb-app/*
      </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I am using SpringBoot 2.0.3.RELEASE and I am also trying to create a WAR of my project which has an angular2 front end and java rest back end. I tried this to exclude my node_modules folder, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Had a scenario where I had to exclude two folders which could be matched by `*scripts` and they were in the resources folder. The first confusion was whether to provide the exclude value as `src/main/resources/*scripts` or as `WEB-INF/classes/*scripts`, i.e. pre or post compilation structure.

Was much important to provide `/**` to get the entire directory being excluded from the war file. In my case, `*scripts/**`.

Here is the final configuration which worked:

```
    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/*scripts/**</packagingExcludes>
```