# exclude folders in maven generated war

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

I've a Java web project, in which I'm using a lot of scss files. All these files are inside /WebContent/scss and compiled to WebContent/css.

I am creating the war using maven-war plugin, and I'd like to exclude this folder (and many other folders) from the generated war.
I've tried using packagingExcludes, but wothout any success until now. Probably there's some misconfiguration I'm not aware of.

This is my pom.xml (in the section related to the maven-war plugin).

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <packagingExcludes>sccs/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750189/maven2-excluding-directory-from-war

Comment: thanks, I tried before with <warSourceExclude> but without results there too

Answer (score 0):

Use [`webResource`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) includes/excludes