# Maven Exclude Files During Build

Tags: java, maven

I am having problems getting Maven to build my webapp without including extraneous development file, such as unminified script and css files.

First i tried using `exclude` in combination with `webResources`

```
<build>     
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>ReportRocket-1</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/resources/</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>annotated-js/*.js</exclude>
                            <exclude>compiled-js/*.js</exclude>
                            <exclude>css/*.css</exclude>
                            <exclude>less/*.less/exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>connection.json</exclude>
                            <exclude>reportRocket.jsp</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The result was the contents of `WEB-INF` being duplicated in the project root and no excluded directories or files.

So, I looked around here and found this: [maven2: excluding directory from WAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750189/maven2-excluding-directory-from-war) but running `mvn clean package` using either `warSourceExcludes` or `packagingExcludes` results in the directories i'm trying to exclude not being, well, excluded...

The build section of my pom.xml

```
<build>     
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>ReportRocket-1</warName>
                <packagingExcludes>
                    src/main/webapp/resources/annotated-js/,
                    src/main/webapp/resources/compiled-js/,
                    src/main/webapp/resources/css/,
                    src/main/webapp/resources/less/,
                    src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/connection.json
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Building the project with these settings results in the following project structure:

```
META-INF
resources
    //desired folders
    annotated-js
    compiled-js
    css
    less
WEB-INF
    // desired files
    connection.json
```

This is my first time using a build tool, so i'm probably overlooking something simple but in the meantime, this is driving me crazy. Any suggestions or obvious problems with my xml?

Comment: instead of `src/main/webapp/resources/annotated-js/` try `annotated-js/*`

Answer (score 3):

First you should read the documentation of the [maven-war-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) cause the packagingExclude is intended for a different purpose, but in your case you need to do the [configuration in that way](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html):

```xml
<configuration>
  <webResources>
    <resource>
      <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
      <directory>src/main/webapp/resources/</directory>
      <!-- there's no default value for this -->
      <excludes>
        <exclude>annotated-js/**</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </webResources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I wrote up my post at the end of the workday, so i hurried and didn't mention that what you suggest is what i tried first. I updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: Than please add a the full pom file and best would be to add an example project to show what does not work (github?)

Comment: I created a git repo containing a demo project demonstrating the problems i am having. When i build the project locally the resulting `.war` contains the folder & contents i am trying to exclude. The pom.xml of the original project is included as `demo.pom`. The repo can be viewed at: https://github.com/andy-rush/MavenProblems/